# Powershell: appending a percent sign to the end of a variable

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

I am trying to add the percent sign ("%") to append to a variable:

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter  "Caption = 'D:'"       
If (!($disk)) {
   $DiskpercentFree = "n/a"
}
Else {
   $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID 
   [float]$size = $disk.Size; 
   [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace;  
   $diskpercentFree1 = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100)
   $Percent = "%" 
   $diskpercentFree = $diskpercentFree1 + $Percent
}
```

But all I get is:

> Cannot convert value "%" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input string
>   was not  in a correct format."

Presumably because it thinks that the "+" operator is making a calculation? I've tried various concat options but can't seem to get it right. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Adding `" "` around your output to treat it as a string and then append the variable onto the end. This means you are able to switch it over from `%` to a string such as `Percent Remaining`.

Hope this helps, you were close!

**Code:**

```
   $disk = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter  "Caption = 'D:'"       
              If (!($disk)) {
                 $DiskpercentFree = "n/a"
                }  
              Else {
                 $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID 
                 [float]$size = $disk.Size; 
                 [float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace;  
                 $diskpercentFree1 = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100)
                 $Percent = '%' 
                 $diskpercentFree = "$diskpercentFree1" + $Percent
                 }
```

**Example Result of `$diskpercentFree`:**

> PS C:\Windows\system32> $DiskpercentFree
>
> 57%

Comment: I chose $diskpercentFree = [String]$diskpercentFree1+"$Percent". I did actually try to convert the variable: "[String]$diskpercentFree". Thanks very much!

Comment: @JDGEEK then technically you should accept the other answer as that was the one that listed that method

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

Assign variable as string:

```
$diskpercentFree = "$diskpercentFree1$Percent"
```

Cast the double value as a string:

```
$diskpercentFree = "$diskpercentFree1" + $Percent
# Or
$diskpercentFree = [string]$diskpercentFree1 + $Percent
```

And no need to use a separate variable for the `%` character:

```
$diskpercentFree = "$diskpercentFree1%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend string formatting if you want to output a value as a percentage. Examples:

```
PS C:\> "{0:P}" -f 1
100.00 %
PS C:\> "{0:P1}" -f .986
98.6 %
PS C:\> "{0:P0}" -f .75
75 %
```

The documentation for `-f` is in the [about_Operators page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) and there are links there to the .NET docs for how to achieve various results.